# Count pixels collected

Tags: java, android

I am creating a game where an image with various coloured pixels are located on a transparent image. The player is moved about by the accelerometer to run into an over the pixels. As the player comes in contact with the pixels it removes them and counts based on colour code. Then the player must move to adopt off point to convert the point-to-point score.

I have the code to move the player. But not sure where start with using image grabbed from a url to use as a backdrop and board to collect pixels.

Can some one help with where to start getting the image and use it as the player board? Another image with drop off point must also be included. The other image is the background.

Comment: You seem to be asking 2 separate questions, but your Question's title doesn't reflect either of them, and the first paragraph just looks like "padding".  Please revise your Question to ask just one question at a time.  Better still, search the site for an answer because both of the questions are undoubtedly duplicates.

Comment: Hint: I think your first question is "how do I download an image", and the second is "how do I set the background image".  (There may be others too ...) Start searching.  If you can't find existing answers on StackOverflow, you are not trying!

Comment: Are you drawing on a Canvas for the game? Or using OpenGL?

Comment: I'm not sure about the size of pixels and amount but if that is discrete, I think you should keep apart image from pixel/collision logic.